# Ansible Lineinfile insert after syntax issues

Tags: ansible

Having some issues with my code and can't figure out the syntax error.

I'm trying to take output from a firewall and put it into an html file but i keep getting stuck. The command in its own separate file outputs a couple of lines of text.  Note destination changed to protect it.

```
- hosts: firewall
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: Hardware Info
    raw: show asset all
    register: output

  - local_action: lineinfile dest=dest destination regexp="{{item}}" insertafter="test" line={{item}} 
    with_items: output.stdout_lines
```

Error:

> - local_action: lineinfile dest=dest insertafter="test"
>     line='{{item}}'
>     ^ here We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets
>     when they start a value. For instance:
>
>   with_items:
>
>   - {{ foo }}
>
> Should be written as:
>
> ```
> with_items:
>   - "{{ foo }}"
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
- local_action: lineinfile dest=dest destination regexp="{{item}}" insertafter="test" line={{item}}
```

To this:

```
- local_action: lineinfile dest=dest destination regexp="{{item}}" insertafter="test" line="{{item}}"
```

The extra quotes should help.

Note lineinfile is terrible from a configuration management point of view, I predict you'll pull your hair out in the future.